# How do i fix this error TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm, logistic-regression, decision-tree

I am trying and testing an outbreak prediction model; but I am facing an error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [12], line 7
      5 for i in [mea,mum,per,pol,rub,sma]:
      6     train_data = train_data.append(i)
----> 7 train_data = train_data.loc[(train_data['Year'] >= '1960') & (train_data['Year'] <= '2011')]
      9 # examine the dataset 
     10 train_data.head()

File c:\Users\Alkaejah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\common.py:72, in _unpack_zerodim_and_defer.<locals>.new_method(self, other)
     68             return NotImplemented
     70 other = item_from_zerodim(other)
---> 72 return method(self, other)

File c:\Users\Alkaejah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arraylike.py:62, in OpsMixin.__ge__(self, other)
     60 @unpack_zerodim_and_defer("__ge__")
     61 def __ge__(self, other):
---> 62     return self._cmp_method(other, operator.ge)

File c:\Users\Alkaejah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py:6243, in Series._cmp_method(self, other, op)
   6240 rvalues = extract_array(other, extract_numpy=True, extract_range=True)
   6242 with np.errstate(all="ignore"):
-> 6243     res_values = ops.comparison_op(lvalues, rvalues, op)
   6245 return self._construct_result(res_values, name=res_name)
...
     35     typ = type(right).__name__
---> 36     raise TypeError(f"Invalid comparison between dtype={left.dtype} and {typ}")
     37 return res_values

TypeError: Invalid comparison between dtype=int64 and str
```

SOURCE CODE:

```py
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore") 
import pandas as pd
import calendar
import numpy as np

def week2month(hep):
    hep['LastDayWeek'] = pd.to_datetime((hep['week']-1).astype(str) + "6", format="%Y%U%w")
    hep['MonthMax'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(hep['LastDayWeek']).month
    hep['Year'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(hep['LastDayWeek']).year
    hep['MonthName'] = [calendar.month_name[i] for i in hep.MonthMax]

def get_input_transform(file_):
    return week2month(pd.read_csv(file_))

hep = get_input_transform('hepatitis.csv')
mea = get_input_transform('measles.csv')
mum = get_input_transform('mumps.csv')
per = get_input_transform('pertussis.csv')
pol = get_input_transform('polio.csv')
rub = get_input_transform('rubella.csv')
sma = get_input_transform('smallpox.csv')

train_data = hep
for i in [mea,mum,per,pol,rub,sma]:
    train_data = train_data.append(i)
train_data = train_data.loc[(train_data['Year'] >= 1960) & (train_data['Year'] <=2011)]
train_data.head()

# some data discrepancies must be resolved (issues like \\N )
train_data_bad = train_data[train_data.cases==train_data.cases.max()]
ind = list(train_data_bad.index)
train_data = train_data.drop(train_data.index[ind])
```

I have tried different article to debug the code and this is a thesis related matter.

Comment: Your error snapshot and source code do not match. The error snapshot has `1960` as string; but source code uses it as string. The error is self explanatory: you are comparing integer to string. Analyse the datatype of `train_data[['Year']].dtypes` and use integer data type for comparison.

Comment: Correction: The error snapshot has 1960 as string; but source code uses it as **integer**.